# Is the correct answer "needs"/ "necessities" or both?

Tags: word-usage

I am confused by the answer of this question

> Water and electricity are .... of modern life.

There are four choices: necessities/ needs/ necessary/ necessity. The correct answer is "needs", but I think "necessities" is also appropriate. Am I wrong? Please explain it to me.

Comment: They are both right. Did your teacher tell you that 'necessities' was wrong?

Comment: I don't think *necessities* is wrong - [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/necessity) has a very similar usage example in *Water is a basic necessity of life*. Personally, I like it more than *needs* in your sentence.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The mock test was compiled by my teacher and he just said "needs" was correct. When I asked about it, he didn't give me a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for your hepful replies